# How to I get heros to pick up and use my armor/weapons?

Tags: towns

I've made lots of nice loot for my heros to wear/equip. They don't seem interested though, only very occasionally picking things up.

I'd say on average they've only got one piece of armour on. The equipment I make varys in level so i'd think there must be something they'd be able to use.

Why aren't my heros interested in my equipment?

Comment: Are they doing a no-armor run for the challenge? :P